# It "is/was" good that everyone contributed to the party that day. - What are the differences?

Tags: meaning, tense

**Example 1**

> It "is" good that everyone contributed to the party that day.

**Example 2**

> It "was" good that everyone contributed to the party that day.

What are the differences?

Answer (score 0):

These are very similar uses, but using “was” implies that the “good feelings” don’t continue to the present.

For example, if you extended the sentences further, you could say something like

> It "is" good that everyone contributed to the party that day, and our next party should go smoothly too.

but

> It "was" good that everyone contributed to the party that day, but the argument afterwards about who contributed the most really ruined the celebration.

Answer (score 0):

In example 1, you are generally commenting on how everyone helped make the party go well. You still feel happy about their contribution.

In example 2, you are commenting on the same thing, but you're implying that something happened after the party, and maybe the following parties didn't go as well as that one.